# socket program post file to php

Tags: php, c, apache, sockets

Yesterday , I asked a question about socket post file data to php page.

Link is here

[Upload and POST file to PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254121/upload-and-post-file-to-php-page)

When I follow the way , I changed my code.

```
char *str="POST /path/upload_file.php HTTP/1.0 \n Host: 00.00.00.00 \n   Content-Disposition: name=2.jpg;filename=2.jpg\r  " ;

write(sockfd, buf, filestat.st_size);
sprintf(send1,"%s%s\r\n",str,buf);
retval= send(sockfd,send1,sizeof(send1),0);
```

When I execute the Program , can get

result: 

501 Method Not Implemented

## Method Not Implemented

to /index.html not supported.

Invalid method in request

---

Apache/1.3.39 Server at localhost Port 80

I guess it's possible :
1. apache can't support something?
     (my apache don't support ssl)
2. http protocol is not details?
3. other?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

First, the `Host` header is part of the HTTP 1.1 specification, and does not apply to HTTP 1.0.

Second, the delimiter for separating headers as well as body is `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Third, you are using the `Content-Disposition` in a request, the way it should be used in a response.

Lastly, you need to send the request as `multipart/form-data`. The answer you've linked to had it right. The request has to respect that format.

I've written a detailed example not so long ago (although in PHP, but the request format stays the same). You can [find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003989/upload-a-file-using-file-get-contents/4247082#4247082).

Comment: He's also got the wrong error message, it's posting to upload_file.php not index.html,